# Find Replace using Wildcard feature

Tags: microsoft-word, wildcards

I would like to modify a word document and I don't know how to do it quickly using the wildcard Find/Replace features.

Example:
[image: ![enter image description here]

I tried to use the find/replace with a wildcard: `<Reception:?<Organization:?` but it takes organization as well. I tried to use `[!]` but that didn't work either

Comment: are there supposed to be images or something?  The formatting of your question is very odd and makes it difficult to follow.

Comment: I edited hope it is better? It is just a word document and an example of content.
The goal is to remove the same kind of content on a 100pages.

Comment: Please add an actual example document, and another which shows what you want to achieve. Just upload the files to some cloud service and add the links to the question. Also please clarify the "Already used"-part - how exactly you used wildcard? How exactly you tried to use `[![`? Screenshots would help - you can't add them yet directly, upload them to imgur or similar and add the direct links, someone will add them to the question.

Comment: I added an example !
About the wildcard, on word Home tab -> Replace -> Find/Replace (more) / add use wildcard.

Comment: A link to a real document with the problem, please, not a screenshot. Also do you know how to use Styles? https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/stylesImportance.htm If not, spend the time to learn, now. Look on the Internet for Jack Lyons, the Editorium, and his free download on Advanced Find and Replace.

Comment: Again, **a sample document would help**. Here is a link that explains how to do this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word-mso_win10-mso_365hp/why-a-sample-file-is-important-for-troubleshooting/9441ae3c-1e92-41c6-9a1f-5b377b08e5a5?tm=1619027698258  Note, no one is going to respond to your duplicate post except to point you back here. It is very difficult to figure out what you want from your examples. It looks like you are trying to delete the Reception area but that is not what you are saying.

Answer (score 0):

For the record, MS Word Find/Replace is in my opinion archaic as it does not offer real advanced search features using regular expression.

That said try the following:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> to open Find and Replace window
2. Find what: `^13Reception:?([a-zA-Z0-9]*^13){1,}`
3. Replace with: Leave empty
4. In Search Options category, enable Use wildcards
5. Press <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

[image]

Comment: Hello @Reddy
I tried but don't know why that is not working

Comment: @killua Have you tried as shown on the picture? Can you share part of your document?

Comment: yes, please there the output I tried different things
https://ibb.co/jVJz8VQ